# Linq select the list of row with defined starting count

Tags: c#, linq

How do I get the list that is limit by the count of row? Without depending in row id.

```
List<object> listname = getitemfrom database();

Var startingcount = 2

Var filteredlist = listname.Where( // row startingpoint = startingcount);
```

Like for example I query list from database then I filter it out by the defined row count (startingcount)
initial Rows: (listname)

1. James , male
2. Clint , male
3. Rose  , female
4. John  , male

Filtered rows: (filteredlist)

3. Rose  , female
4. John. , Male

The result should be kind of like this.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are looking for `Skip()`?

Comment: While duplicate I selected talks about 1 you can really use any number in the suggested `Skip(1)` answer. Hopefully that is enough for you as answer - [edit] post otherwise to clarify.